# Una RNA multicapa que recibe como entrada una imagen y de salida da la imagen binarizada, ¿que estructura debe tener la red?

Tags: python, redes-neuronales

El problema a resolver es crear una RNA multicapa que reciba fotos de cargas de madera y que la salida sea la imagen binarizada, de forma que las tablas sean blancas y el resto(incluidos los huecos entre tablas) sea negro.

Ejemplo:
Imagen original de 2000x1000 px (En escala de grises)
Divido la imagen en n secciones de 100x50 px para entrenar la red.
En la red introduzco estas secciones y como solución las secciones binarizadas previamente con filtros.
Tras entrenarla busco que la red reciba imagenes y de como salida la imagen binarizada.

¿Que estructura debe tener la red? (En cuanto a capas y neuronas por capa, especificamente en la salida)
Porque los ejemplos que pude encontrar son de redes para clasificación, con lo que la capa de salida tiene solo una salida (0 o 1, Ejemplo típico: Perro o Gato), pero en este caso yo estoy buscando que la salida sea una imagen (array/matriz) que repersente las imagenes en binario y supongo que no puede ser con una sola neurona en la capa de salida.

*Nota: Sé que quizas este proceso no es el mejor para binarizar imágenes, pero estoy interesado en crear este tipo de red en python (Preferiblemente sin utilizar librerías avanzadas como tensorflow, keras...)

Answer (score 2):

La palabra clave por la que debes buscar es *semantic segmentation*. Estos son algoritmos que clasifican **cada pixel** de la imagen en una categoría diferente.

Normalmente hay muchas categorías ("coche", "persona", "señal de tráfico", etc.) y producen como resultado una imagen multicolor en la que por ejemplo los pixeles azules pertenecen a coches, los rojos a personas, los amarillos a señales...

Por ejemplo (superponiendo la salida con la entrada):

[image: Imagen segmentada semánticamente]

En tu caso habría sólo una categoría: "madera", y el resultado tendría de un color los pixeles que son de madera (y de otro todo lo demás).

El problema es que para entrenar la red de modo que pueda decidir si algo es o no madera, tienes que suministrarle muchas imágenes de ejemplo que estén *etiquetadas*, es decir, que manualmente tendrás que segmentarlas tú antes (colorear los pixeles que son "madera"). Supongo que en esta tarea puedes ayudarte de otros métodos que hayas desarrollado, como umbralización, etc.

Hay muchas redes neuronales diferentes capaces hacer *semantic segmentation*, y tendrás que investigar cuál se adapta mejor a tu caso. De cualquier forma no te recomiendo implementarla "de cero" en python, pues tardará siglos en entrenarse. Las redes neuronales hacen uso intensivo de cálculos matriciales y tensoriales, y tener una biblioteca como tensorflow o keras optimizada y capaz de aprovechar el paralelismo de una GPU es algo fundamental.

[Aquí por ejemplo](https://divamgupta.com/image-segmentation/2019/06/06/deep-learning-semantic-segmentation-keras.html) tienes un artículo de los muchos existente por donde puedes empezar a mirar (del cual he sacado la imagen que aparece al principio).